# Why could the Homestake experiment only detect electron neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

The [Homestake experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestake_experiment) measured the incoming electron neutrino flux via

$$\nu_{e}+ Cl^{37} \rightarrow Ar^{37} +e^{-}$$

Why does this reaction not apply to the other neutrino flavours? i.e. what disallows

$$\nu_{\mu}+ Cl^{37} \rightarrow Ar^{37} +\mu^{-}$$

$$\nu_{\tau}+ Cl^{37} \rightarrow Ar^{37}+ \tau^{-}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solar neutrinos have energies under 10 MeV. There isn't enough energy to make heavy leptons.

That's really the whole story.